# Java web application object dispatching

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications

Is HttpSession object available to all the applications that is running in the same java enterprise application server?

For my work, i have login application which does the authentication and then it will be forwarded to another application.In Second application, filter is added to prevent the direct access to the URL

ServletContext - gets only the context of the current webapplication.

What is the correct approach to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HttpSession objects are scoped at the application (or servlet context) level.

An excerpt from [Java™ Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/):

> HttpSession objects must be scoped at the application (or servlet
>   context) level. The underlying mechanism, such as the cookie used to
>   establish the session, can be the same for different contexts, but the
>   object referenced, including the attributes in that object, must never
>   be shared between contexts by the container.
>
> To illustrate this requirement with an example: **if a servlet uses the
>   RequestDispatcher to call a servlet in another Web application, any
>   sessions created for and visible to the servlet being called must be
>   different from those visible to the calling servlet.**

An approach to handle this scenario:

You can get access to the resources available for one servlet context from the other by using [servletContext.getContext("/otherWebappContext")](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContext%28java.lang.String%29) method as below:

```
request.setAttribute("userToken", <token>);
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = getServletContext().getContext(
                "/otherWebappContext").getRequestDispatcher("/resource");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

**But any session created for the servlet being called is different from that of the calling servlet**. Once the request is forwarded to the second application, it can create a new session with the data received through the request attributes.

But for security reasons, servlet containers normally prevent these cross-context operations. So you need to change the default behavior. For example, in Tomcat 6 you need to set the crossContext attribute to "true" for `<Context>` element in TOMCAT_HOME/conf/context.xml file as below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context crossContext="true">

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

Answer (score 0):

No HttpSession Object is not available to all the applications present in the same server.
To verify,

create 2 apps,
In one app use seesion.setAttribute("hello","hello");
Now run second app

```
if(session.getAttribute("hello")==null)
{
//some codes to check
}
else

{
//some codes to check
}
```

You will see **if** part will be executed

Answer (score 0):

No HttpSession objects are not shared among applications. The standard way of sharing an information among different applications in a container is to use ServletContext. The only limitation with ServletContext is that if a web applicationa is distributed between multiple JVM this will not work because context info is within one JVM.

Comment: But ServletContext gets only thw current web application context